# Receive messages in the background

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

Java Client-Server.
It is necessary to receive messages from the client in the background.
I'm trying to receive messages in the background:

```
public Server() throws IOException {
           try {
        serverSocket=new ServerSocket(1234);
        fromclient= serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Socket created");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Socket not created");
    }
    try {
        in  = new BufferedReader(new
                InputStreamReader(fromclient.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    out = new PrintWriter(fromclient.getOutputStream(),true);
    String         input,output;
}
```

Bacground part:

```
 public void run(ServerSocket welcomeSocket) throws IOException {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.
                accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println(clientSentence);
        capitalizedSentence =
                clientSentence.toUpperCase() + '\n';
        outToClient.writeBytes(capitalizedSentence);
    }
```

And send message in Client part:

```
  Client client=new Client();
    client.Connect();
   client.sendToServer("text test");
   Run run=new Run();

  void run() throws IOException {
            BufferedReader inFromUser =
                    new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket ("127.0.0.1",6789);
            DataOutputStream outToServer =
                    new DataOutputStream(
                            clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader inFromServer =
                    new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(
                                    clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
           // while (true) {
                outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + "\n");
                modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
                System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + modifiedSentence);
            //}
            //     clientSocket.close();
        }
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

You opened a ServerSocket on port 1234 and then the Socket to 6789. Try to use the same port :)